# How to select mysql value and store it into a variable C#

Tags: c#, mysql

so I have a table and I want to select a value from the table and store it into a C# variable.

What I have right now is this

```
String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
try
{
    conn.Open();
    queryStr = "";
    queryStr = "SELECT ipaddress from robolinks where roboID=?roboID";

    cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?roboID", roboID);
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    conn.Close();

//after closing the connection, get the ipaddress and key it into web browser.

}
catch(Exception)
{

}
```

So I know I have already selected it but how do I manipulate ipaddress in C#?

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Please share the code that you are using for executing this query,

Comment: What do you mean by manipulating the `ipaddress`? Do you mean like updating it in the Database or what exactly?

Comment: I want to store the selected IP address into a variable so I can programmically open the web browser and key in the ip address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you use `ExecuteReader` then you need to get values first and only then close connection.
Second is `ExecuteReader` is returning `SqlDataReader` so if you want to get some value from Sql you need to assign the return variable of `ExecuteReader` to some value

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Now, using manual ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx ) start coding:

```
string roboIp;
// Because you know that id is int so imho you don't need parameters.
queryStr = "SELECT ipaddress from robolinks where roboID="+roboID+";";
// This is right.
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
conn.Open();
var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Now check if any rows returned.
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    dr.Read();// Get first record.
    roboIp = dr.GetString(0);// Get value of first column as string.
}
dr.Close();// Close reader.
conn.Close();// Close connection.
```

But if you select only one value, then better use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`

```
string roboIp;
queryStr = "SELECT ipaddress from robolinks where roboID="+roboID+";";
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
conn.Open();
var queryResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();//Return an object so first check for null
if(queryResult!=null)
    // If we have result, then convert it from object to string.
    roboIp = Convert.ToString(queryResult);
else
    // Else make id = "" so you can later check it.
    roboIp = "";
```

Comment: Upd. Edited because i think Ip is stored as string.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
        SQL = "Select * from IPQC_modelParameter where full_model='" & lblModel.Text & "' and drawing_no='" & lblDrwing.Text & "' and machine_name='" & cbmachnum.Text & "' and parameter='" & tempparam & "' "
        Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, connection)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            txtucl.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ucl").ToString

        End Using
    End Using
```

For Reference: Im using vbnet, you can just convert it to c# syntax

Comment: thank you for not down voting @Sergio. Do I need to delete my answer?

Comment: No =) Someone could find it helpfull ;)